# bagisto elevatezoom not working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, elevatezoom

I am using the elevate Zoom plugin to show zoomed images. The first time this plugin is not working, but when clicking on the second image it's working properly.

```
$('#active-product-image').ezPlus();
```

Plugin options not working, I used only basic options used but it didn't work. It applied the Mousewheel Zoom option automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this thing has been fixed in master. Please, take a pull from the master,
https://github.com/bagisto/bagisto.